# Trying to highlight selected divs and auto pause youtube videos when div is hidden

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, show-hide

TL;DR DEMO HERE - http://jsfiddle.net/ZcMkt/492/

Hopefully someone can help as this is frying my brain.

I am building a video page with 5 YouTube videos embedded on it. Only one of the videos is visible at a time. There is top navigation (to select each video) and side navigation (again to select a video). As well as this there is also navigation at the bottom (underneath the video div), which is used to select either the video content or displaying a hidden div (to replace the video div) with one containing photos.

So the issues I'm having:

1). I cant get the videos to auto pause when another one is selected via the navigation

2). The top nav and side nav (same links to videos) wont highlight together when selected.

3). When selecting the bottom nav (for photos) I cant figure out how to disable the video links (5) and replace those links with 5 photo divs.

```
HTML
====
<div class="Video">

<div class="VideoTop">
<ul class="nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href=".tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href=".tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href=".tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
<li><a href=".tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
<li><a href=".tab5">Tab 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="VideoSide">
<ul class="nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href=".tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href=".tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href=".tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
<li><a href=".tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
<li><a href=".tab5">Tab 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="video-div">
<section class="tab-content tab1 active">
<iframe id="player1" width="350" height="197" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dg4rylxSg5c?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>

<section class="tab-content tab2 hide">
<iframe id="player2" width="350" height="197" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/IQgS3lcpWLQ?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>

<section class="tab-content tab3 hide">
<iframe id="player3" width="350" height="197" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/E07tybE1sPE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>

<section class="tab-content tab4 hide">
<iframe id="player4" width="350" height="197" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FZ5Ua0e2ZIw?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>

<section class="tab-content tab5 hide">
<iframe id="player5" width="350" height="197" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ZpAEWbopYl8?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>

<section class="tab-content tab6 hide">
<a href="link1.html"><img src="http://www.clickerzoneuk.co.uk/cz/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/PuppySmall.jpg" /></a>
<a href="link2.html"><img src="http://www.clickerzoneuk.co.uk/cz/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/AkitaPuppies-300x162.jpg" /></a>
<a href="link3.html"><img src="http://www.clickerzoneuk.co.uk/cz/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/DogBathing-300x198.jpg" /></a>
</section>


</div>

<div class="viewTabs">
<ul class="nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href=".tab1">View Video</a></li>
<li><a href=".tab6">View Photos</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<section class="tab-content tab1 active">
<div class="Box1">
<p>Text box 1</p>
</div>
</section>

<section class="tab-content tab2 hide">
<div class="Box2">
<p>Text box 2</p>
</div>
</section>

<section class="tab-content tab3 hide">
<div class="Box3">
<p>Text box 3</p>
</div>
</section>

<section class="tab-content tab4 hide">
<div class="Box4">
<p>Text box 4</p>
</div>
</section>

<section class="tab-content tab5 hide">
<div class="Box5">
<p>Text box 5</p>
</div>
</section>

</div>

CSS
====

.Video  {background:#000;  padding: 15px;}
.VideoTop   {margin-bottom:15px}
.VideoTop ul    {margin-bottom: 5px;}
.VideoTop li    {display: inline;font-size: 14px;}
.VideoTop a {background: #434343; text-transform:uppercase}
.VideoSide {float:right; width:32%;}
.VideoSide li {display: block;margin-bottom: 1px;}
.VideoSide a    {background: #434343; text-transform:uppercase}
.viewTabs   {background:#000;  padding: 5px;}
.viewTabs ul    {margin-top:5px}
.viewTabs li    {display:inline; font-size:14px;}
.viewTabs a {background:#434343; text-transform:uppercase; padding:5px;}
.nav {list-style: none;}
.nav > li > a {display: block;}
.VideoSide a    {padding: 26px 20px 18px 20px;display: block;height: 25px;}
.VideoTop a {padding: 7px 16px 7px 15px;display: inline;}
.nav-tabs > .active > a {color: #fff;cursor: default;background-color: #666;}
.nav-tabs a:hover   {background:#000;color:#fff;}
.tab-content.active {display: block;}
.tab-content.hide {display: none;}
#video-div  {min-height:350px;} 
#video-div  img {margin:15px}
img.rightFloat  {float:right}

JQUERY
======

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs > li > a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();//stop browser to take action for clicked anchor

    //get displaying tab content jQuery selector
    var active_tab_selector = $('.nav-tabs > li.active > a').attr('href');                  

    //find active navigation and remove 'active' css
    var actived_nav = $('.nav-tabs > li.active');
    actived_nav.removeClass('active');

    //add 'active' css into clicked navigation
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');

    //hide displaying tab content
    $(active_tab_selector).removeClass('active');
    $(active_tab_selector).addClass('hide');

    //show target tab content
    var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hide');
    $(target_tab_selector).addClass('active');
     });
  });
$(function() {
/* elt: Optionally, a HTMLIFrameElement. This frame's video will be played,
 *       if possible. Other videos will be paused*/
function playVideoAndPauseOthers(frame) {
    $('iframe[src*="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"]').each(function(i) {
        var func = this === frame ? 'playVideo' : 'pauseVideo';
        this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func +         '","args":""}', '*');
    });
}
$('.ultimateOrgasmVideo a[href^=".tab"]').click(function() {
    var frameId = /.tab(\d+)/.exec($(this).attr('href'));
    if (frameId !== null) {
        frameId = frameId[1]; // Get frameId
        playVideoAndPauseOthers($('#video-div' + frameId + ' iframe')[0]);
    }
});
});
```